# Adjusting plot and data table layout in Shiny in R; maintain alignment after updating plot and data table

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, datatable

I am creating a feature of a dashboard which plots the counts of a grouping variable and a data table providing descriptive information. The plot and the data table are placed on top of each other. The layout of my table is in a wide format, with a date variable along the top as column names. The x-axis of the plot is also a date variable.

What I am aiming to do is to display the column of the data table directly under the corresponding date on the x-axis. And when the outputs are reactively updated, the dates on the plot x-axis are positioned over their respective column names in the data table below.

Here is a mock example:-

**Data**

```
#relevant libraries
library(wakefield)#for generating the Status variable
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(Pareto)
library(uuid)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)


#mock data creation
set.seed(1)
#data<-data.frame()
Date<-seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "1 day")
Date<-sample(rep(Date,each=10),replace = T)

event<-r_sample_factor(x = c("Wrestling", "Drama", 
                                    "Information", "Football", "Rugby", "Movie", "Music", "News"), n=length(eventDate))

Hour<-r_sample_factor(x = c(0:23), n=length(Date))

Group<-r_sample_factor(x = c("A","B","C","D","E"), n=length(Date))

#creating user ID

set.seed(1)

n_users <- 100
n_rows <- 3650

relative_probs <- rPareto(n = n_users, t = 1, alpha = 0.3, truncation = 500) 
unique_ids <- UUIDgenerate(n = n_users)

AnonID <- sample(unique_ids, size = n_rows, prob = relative_probs, replace = TRUE)


data<-data.frame(AnonID,Group,Date,Hour,event)
data$Hour<-as.numeric(data$Hour)
head(data)
```

**Shiny code**

```
#ui================================
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example panel"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("example text",
             sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                          dateRangeInput("daterange","Select dates", format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                                         start = min("2015-01-01"),
                                         end = max("2015-01-31")),
                          numericInput("hourmin", "Select mininum hour",10,0,23),
                          numericInput("hourmax", "Select maximum hour", 22,0,23)),#end of sidebarPanel
             mainPanel(
               column(width = 10, plotOutput("barplot", width = "100%")),
                      column(width = 8, dataTableOutput("table"))
             )#end of mainPanel
                          
             )
             )#end of tabPanel
  )#end of tabsetPanel
)#end of fluidPage


#server===========================================

server<-function(input,output,session){

  
 rv <- reactiveVal(NULL)  
  
  observe({
    
    rv(data)
  
    output$table<-renderDataTable({
      rv()%>%
      filter(Date>=input$daterange[1] & Date<=input$daterange[2])%>%
      filter(Hour>=input$hourmin & Hour<=input$hourmax)%>%
      arrange(desc(Date))%>%
      group_by(event, Hour,Date)%>%
      arrange(Hour,Date)%>%
      summarise(Programme=event, .groups = 'drop')%>%
      mutate(rn=rowid(Hour,Date))%>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = Date,values_from = Programme)%>%
      select(-rn)
    })
    
    output$barplot<-renderPlot({
      
      rv()%>%
        filter(Date>=input$daterange[1] & Date<=input$daterange[2])%>%
        filter(Hour>=input$hourmin & Hour<=input$hourmax)%>%
        group_by(Date,Group)%>%
        summarise(UniqueID=n_distinct(AnonID))%>%
        ggplot()+
        geom_bar(aes(x=Date,y=UniqueID, fill=Group), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
        
      
    })
    
    })#end of observe
  }

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Which gives you this :-

[image]

Is there a away to match the dates on the plot x-axis to the columns in the data table beneath, as in position wise and in chronological order? Sort of speak, linking the plot and table together.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can use `crosstalk` package.

Comment: Out of interest, is it possible to link two different datasets with ```crosstalk``` package, with the only common feature between the two datasets is a Date column?

Comment: You can merge the two datasets into one by Date column and then create the SharedData object.